# How does ssh tunneling and port forwarding work without ping?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to do ssh tunneling:

ssh -L 1234:yahoo.com:80 home.abc.com

when i run this, it SSHs me into home.abc.com. I have following questions:

1. from my local box, i am not able to ping home.abc.com, then how it is able to ssh me to this box?
2. from home.abc.com, i am able to ping yahoo.com, but when i run localhost:1234 locally, i am not able to connect (i was expecting that running localhost:1234 will open yahoo.com locally). Why it is not working?
3. why does above command ssh me into home.abc.com, i thought it was just a tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

What is commonly called a "ping" is nothing but a specific network request that can

- easily be blocked by any firewall
- take a different route through the network compared to other packages
- be seen as a very unreliable test for network purposes.

Specifically `ping` uses a decent port which is different from that ssh typically uses or the ones you specified. Take a look at the options commands like `ping` and `traceroute` offer to get an impression. Also it certainly makes sense to understand *how* a "ping" actually works, what it does and that it is not some magic to test a connection. I suggest you start reading about "ping" and "traceroute" over at WikiPedia...

About the ssh command actually logging you in (or offering to) on the target system: your command is *not* "just a tunnel"! Instead your command says: open a ssh connection to host `home.abc.com` *AND* in addition *try* to setup a tunnel as specified in the options.

About your final attempt to *use* that tunnel: make sure the tunnel actually got setup, ssh will output an error otherwise on standard error out. *If* there are no blocking firewalls inbetween then you should be able to request yahoos starting page with a request to `http://localhost:1234`.

Comment: How can i know if my tunnel is set up correctly or not? Also, what should i do to just setup the tunnel and not ssh into the machine?

Comment: Also "ssh -L <local-port-to-listen>:<remote-host>:<remote-port> <gateway>" is the syntax. So, localhost:1234 should take me to yahoo.com right, as my local port is 1234 and home.abc.com is gateway?

Comment: If there is a problem setting up the tunnel then ssh will output an error message on the stderr pipe.

Comment: Take a look at the `-f` and the `-n` flag ssh offers (_if_ we are talking about the openssh implementation). Or even better: read the "man page" about ssh: `man ssh`. A commands man page _always_ is the first place to look for information about usage details.

Comment: Indeed, _if_ the tunnel is set up, then a request to `http://localhost:1234` will be relayed to `http://yahoo:80`. Note that in case the remote server redirects you to another url, then you will not be using that previous tunnel for that redirected request. The tunnel has no "rewriting features" or anything like for example apaches reverse proxy feature does.

Answer (score 0):

ping and ssh use different IP protocols.  Most of the time when talking about the internet people think of the TCP or UDP protocols, and what TCP or UDP port numbers particular applications use.  ping on the otherhand does not use TCP or UDP, but rather ICMP.

There is a [list of IP protocols](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) that [iana.org](http://www.iana.org) has formerly recognised.

Firewalls and routers can treat IP packets differently depending on a multitude of factors, including the protocol being used.  Since some people abuse the ICMP features required for ping to function, many firewalls will block this sort of traffic by default.

The abuse of ICMP is typically confined to confirming whether or not a device is active at a particular IP address without going through all of the available protocols, and for TCP and udp all of the port numbers.  Even just scanning the popular TCP/UDP port numbers for recognisable applications to prompt the device to respond takes time.